# xampp Can't select database

Tags: database, select

I use Can't select database MySQL, php,

I have code config.php

```html
<?php
 $config["sql_host"] = "127.0.0.1";
 $config["sql_user"] = "root";
 $config["sql_pass"] = "password123";
 $db_name["db_name"] = "sql123";
?>
```

and global.php

```html
  global $config,$data_sql;
  $data_sql = mysqli_connect($config["sql_host"], $config["sql_user"], $config["sql_pass"]);
  if (!$data_sql) die("Can't connect to MySql");
  mysqli_select_db($db_name["db_name"],$data_sql) or die("Can't select database");
```

and I receive this: 
Can't select database

anyone can help me?